# Auslander-Reiten-Quivers of representation-finite algebras having different 3-dimensional forms

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, quivers

I am looking for references, where I can find (pictures of) connected Auslander-Reiten-Quivers of representation-finite $k$-algebras ($k$ is a (preferably, but not necessarily finite) field) with one or more of the following properties:

1) the Auslander-Reiten quiver contains two cylinders (so, there are periodic modules), but also many non-periodic modules

2) the Auslander-Reiten quiver contains a Moebius strip, but also many non-periodic modules

In the first case, I was thinking of something like

[image]

where the colored modules are identified...but with 2 cylinders (I should have added the second one at the top of the non-Tau-periodic modules)...and in the second case, I was thinking of something like

[image]

But, I'm not sure, if any of these can happen...

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Having some algebras as examples, but without the pictures, would also be nice.

Comment: Insofar as these are 1-complexes not 2-complexes, are these containment questions well-defined? (They may be, in which case I'd like to hear the well definition.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I edited the question.

Comment: "Thiele: The topological structure of Auslander-Reiten quivers of special string algebras" seems to be related.